Accessing InterlockedExchange function using ctypes
I am trying to access InterLockedExchange function by reading dlls in windows using ctypes python library. My broader goal is to implement atomic operations while I am using mmap in different services. The issue is I am not able to find this function
import ctypes
dll_path = 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'
kernel32 = ctypes.CDLL(dll_path)
interlocked_exchange = kernel32.InterlockedExchange

AttributeError: function 'InterlockedExchange' not found

Escape backslashes or use an r-string

You don’t need the full path for a system DLL. Use WinDLL('kernel32')

InterlockedExchange is an intrinsic function of the compiler and not exposed via a DLL function because it is used by inline functions.  See the Remarks section of the documentation link:

This function is implemented using a compiler intrinsic where
possible. For more information, see the WinBase.h header file and
_InterlockedExchange.

If you want to access intrinsic functions make a DLL that exposes functions that call them and import that DLL and its functions with ctypes instead.
